# How to enable HTTPS on AWS Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, https

#### Hi there,

I have been struggling running a single instance Docker with HTTPS on AWS.

The HTTP access is working properly but I cannot access HTTPS (Google Chrome showing "This site can't be reached").

Here we have a single instance with Elastic Beanstalk. So there is no Load Balancer, and the certificates are hosted on the instance.

I followed this tutorial: [AWS HTTPS Single Instance Docker](http://I%20use%20a%20single%20instance%20with%20Elastic%20Beanstalk.%20So%20there%20is%20no%20Load%20Balancer,%20and%20the%20certificates%20are%20hosted%20on%20the%20instance.%20%20Basically%20I%20followed%20this%20tutorial:%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html)

The Instance is working properly, my certificates are uploaded properly and the nginx config too.
This is what I got so far:

- Tried to setup the Security Group to allow TCP 443, did not work.
- Tried to setup the Security Group to allow All Traffic to Anywhere, did not work.
- HTTP access from my domain name is working, which makes me believe it is not a DNS problem.
- HTTPS access is working with curl from the instance, so nginx config looks good to me (with log access working properly).
- The `/var/log/nginx/access.log` does not shows any results when I hit my domain name with HTTPS.

**Here is my Security Group values**

```
Port range    Protocol    Source                    Security groups
80            TCP         sg-03d37000000000000      MY_SECURITY_GROUP
All           All         0.0.0.0/0                 MY_SECURITY_GROUP
All           All         ::/0                      MY_SECURITY_GROUP
443           TCP         0.0.0.0/0                 MY_SECURITY_GROUP
```

**When I hit the instance nginx in HTTPS**

(insecure is because certificate domain name is not 127.0.0.1, the API result is correct)

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-345-67-89 nginx]$ curl --insecure https://127.0.0.1
{"status":"ok","api":"sdk"}
```

**This is what I get from Google Chrome when trying to access the website**
[Google Chrome showing "This site can't be reached"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BHOz.png)

**Here is the logs from nginx access**

```
[ec2-user@ip-123-345-67-89 nginx]$ tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log
AWS_IP    - - [01/Oct/2020:14:02:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 56 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                               "-"
MY_IP     - - [01/Oct/2020:14:02:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0  "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) ..." "123.345.67.89"
AWS_IP    - - [01/Oct/2020:14:02:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 56 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                               "-"
AWS_IP    - - [01/Oct/2020:14:03:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 56 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                               "-"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Oct/2020:14:03:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 27 "-" "curl/7.61.1"                                         "-"
AWS_IP    - - [01/Oct/2020:14:03:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 56 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"                               "-"
```

So far I believe there is something wrong between my AWS config and the instance as everything is working on the instance.

But the AWS Config looks good to me so I have no other ideas about the origin of my issue.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot for reading all of this.

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? I see you have `ELB-HealthChecker` so you are using Application load balancer? The "Security Group values" are for ALB or your instances? If you have ALB, where did you deploy your SSL cert, on the ALB or instances?

Comment: Hi @Marcin,
Sorry I thought `single instance` was clear enough (I am not expert on AWS).
I use a single instance with Elastic Beanstalk. So there is no Load Balancer, and the certificates are hosted on the instance.

Basically I followed this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-docker.html

Comment: Your logs show entries from "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0". Where does it come from if you don't have load balancer?

Comment: That was it! thank you mate.
On my Elastic Beanstalk environment, under `Configuration > Capacity` the `environment type` was set to **Load Balanced**.
I changed it to **Single Instance** and it is now working.

My mistake was to guess the Elastic Beanstalk configuration would be the same from PHP (what I had before) to Docker.

You can post this as answer so I can solve this one.

Comment: No problem and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by using load-balanced EB environment by mistake, rather then single-instance one.

The **solution** was to change the load-balanced EB environment to single-instance one in EB console.

Comment: How can we have HTTPS enabled container in AWS ECS

Comment: @sks123245 You can make a new question about this. But generally you would need to have self-signed ssl certificates, and HTTPS protocal in your target group settings.